# Porting CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage to normal OpenGL ES methods

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, core-video

I'm working on an app that feeds video frames coming from the camera into an OpenGL ES texture to create some effects. The app uses Core Video and its many convenience methods to create OpenGL textures and caches.

Now I'd like to use static images instead of the video buffer, and I'm looking for standard OpenGL methods in place of those available with Core Video.

For example:

- CVOpenGLESTextureRef;
- CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef;
- CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage();
- CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget();
- CVOpenGLESTextureGetName();
- CVOpenGLESTextureCacheFlush();

What are the standard OpenGL types and methods that I can use in place of the code above to load and create a texture from a normale image?

Thanks

****EDIT****

Following Brad's suggestion I was able to do some progress... but still doesn't work correctly. I believe the problem is that the shader is expecting two separate textures to work properly. One for the Y plane and one for the UV plane.

Here's the code used to set them up

```
// Y-plane
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, _videoTextureCache, pixelBuffer, NULL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RED_EXT, _textureWidth, _textureHeight, GL_RED_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &_lumaTexture);
glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(_lumaTexture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(_lumaTexture));
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

// UV-plane
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, _videoTextureCache, pixelBuffer, NULL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RG_EXT, _textureWidth/2, _textureHeight/2, GL_RG_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 1, &_chromaTexture);
glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(_chromaTexture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(_chromaTexture));
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

So I changed it this way:

here's the setup

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glGenTextures(1, &_lumaImageTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _lumaImageTexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glGenTextures(1, &_chromaImageTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _chromaImageTexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

and here is how I create them

```
// Y-plane
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _lumaImageTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, _textureWidth, _textureHeight, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

// UV-plane
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _chromaImageTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, _textureWidth, _textureHeight, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

I guess the problem is in one of the parameters in the glTexImage2D function. I tried different combinations with different results... but never the correct one :)

Answer (score 2):

All those methods do is hand you an OpenGL ES texture that corresponds to a CVPixelBuffer. Before these were introduced in iOS 5.0, we had to manually grab the pixel data from a CVPixelBuffer and upload that to a texture. You'd use the same process for a static image pulled from another source (unless you wanted to use some of the GLKit convenience classes).

The following is code that I've used for uploading static images. First, you need to get the image into a BGRA byte array:

```
if (shouldRedrawUsingCoreGraphics)
{
    // For resized image, redraw
    imageData = (GLubyte *) calloc(1, (int)pixelSizeToUseForTexture.width * (int)pixelSizeToUseForTexture.height * 4);

    CGColorSpaceRef genericRGBColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();    
    CGContextRef imageContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(imageData, (int)pixelSizeToUseForTexture.width, (int)pixelSizeToUseForTexture.height, 8, (int)pixelSizeToUseForTexture.width * 4, genericRGBColorspace,  kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGContextDrawImage(imageContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, pixelSizeToUseForTexture.width, pixelSizeToUseForTexture.height), newImageSource);
    CGContextRelease(imageContext);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(genericRGBColorspace);
}
else
{
    // Access the raw image bytes directly
    dataFromImageDataProvider = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(newImageSource));
    imageData = (GLubyte *)CFDataGetBytePtr(dataFromImageDataProvider);
}
```

In the above code, `newImageSource` is a CGImageRef. This shows two different paths for extracting bitmap data, with the first path surprisingly being faster in every benchmark I've run.

Once you have that, you simply need to upload it to your OpenGL ES texture:

```
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, outputTexture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, (int)pixelSizeToUseForTexture.width, (int)pixelSizeToUseForTexture.height, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
```

This assumes that you've already created outputTexture using something like the following:

```
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glGenTextures(1, &outputTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, outputTexture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // This is necessary for non-power-of-two textures
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

and that the correct EAGLContext is associated with the current thread by using `+setCurrentContext:`.

If I may make a suggestion, why not take a look at [my open source framework](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) that handles all of this for you in order to do image processing tasks? It might save you some effort here.

Comment: Hi Brad, I know your framework... amazing work indeed! However I just thought it was too much overhead for such simple task. I'll try to follow your suggestion and see if I can make it work this way first. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Brad, thanks! It's kind of working... I get the texture, only problem is that it's green-ish. Is that because the texture is in the wrong format and doesn't include all the necessary bit for each channel? Sorry if the question is not very precise... but I'm a complete noob with OpenGL. :)

Comment: @Andrea - If it's green, but the image still shows and it isn't filled with a bunch of diagonal lines, you probably have an issue with the byte order of the input image. It might be taking in RGBA instead of BGRA, or ARGB or ABGR. The above settings I use for the bitmap context are specifically chosen to generate BGRA frames for use with the later texture upload. Make sure you aren't using context settings other than those.

Comment: I followed your code precisely, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I think I have a good idea of the reason. Please check the edit to my original question... I added more details. (how do I do and @yourname with your name?)

Comment: @Andrea - Yes, of course for planar YUV this won't work as described above. When you said "Now I'd like to use static images" I assumed you were pulling from a UIImage source, where you could draw into a BGRA image buffer. You're asking a totally different question now. For YUV planar sources, you're going to need to replace the `glTexImage2d()` parameters for your Y and UV textures with the parameters from the texture cache functions you show in the first code from your update. Note the new byte sizes and the use of `GL_RED_EXT` and `GL_RG_EXT` texture types.

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks! I haven't explained my self very well. Common problem when you are not a native speaker. BTW... I looked around on SO and discovered that you have already answered similar questions before. To be more specific, I'm working on the GLCameraRipple example made by Apple. :) I basically want to be able to switch between the camera feed and a static jpg file. I'm going to go through the answers you gave in the other posts first. Hopefully I should be able to work out the solution to my problem.